# Connect Route 53 to DigitalOcean CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, digital-ocean, cdn, amazon-route53

I'm using Route 53 as my DNS provider and I'd like to use DigitalOcean's CDN How would I go about routing a subdomain to a DO CDN?

Would a CNAME work?

`cdn.mydomain.com CNAME mydospace.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com`

Or is there another way to go about it?

Maybe adding an NS record from my subdomain to DigitalOcean NS and then using DO's networking?

**------------ EDIT: -------------**

Seems like CNAME doesn't work with the `cdn` endpoint but it does work if you omit the `cdn` part, i.e. `mydospace.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com`

But! now it gives back a NoSuchBucket Error

Comment: Why wouldn't a CNAME work?

Comment: Hmm I tried that... I'm actually getting a 404 now with CNAME so could be it being routed correctly but the servers are blocking the request because of the host header

Comment: Check https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/customize-cdn-endpoint/

Comment: @DusanBajic thanks, but for that to work you have to use the DO DNS, otherwise they don't let you select a subdomain

Comment: I don't use that service, but from reading the page it does not appear that it is mandatory to use DO DNS

Comment: Maybe if I add a custom certificate that I generate myself

Answer (score -1):

> Would a CNAME work?
>
> `cdn.mydomain.com CNAME mydospace.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com`

Yes, that's exactly what you need to do.  You don't actually need to use Digital Ocean's DNS.  You just need to set this CNAME up on wherever you've hosted your DNS.

Next, you need to manually install an SSL certificate.  You can generate this manually via LetsEncrypt, or you can purchase one.

Once your certificate is in place, it will work fine.

> Seems like CNAME doesn't work with the cdn endpoint but it does work if you omit the cdn part, i.e. mydospace.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com

No, this isn't accurate.  The CNAME *must* be set to the CDN endpoint.